Number of Shortest Paths Through Any Edge on a Discrete Torus
I am currently stuck with the following problem: Consider the setting of a random walk on a discrete torus with $d$ dimensions and grid Size $L$. That means considering a simple (no loops or multiple edges) graph $(E,K)$ with set of vertices $$E=[0,L-1]^{d}\cap \mathbb Z^d$$ and set of edges $K\subset E\times E$. There exists an edge $e=(x,y)$ if $x$ and $y$ are neighbors, i.e., $$|x-y|=1$$2D Torus: Leonid_2 - Own Work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=8643414
Let $\gamma_{x,y}$ be the shortest path from vertex $x$ to $y$ (least amount of edges to cross)
I am  interested in a sort of "bottleneck measure", i.e., the maximum number of shortest paths that pass through an edge $e$, i.e., $$\max_{e\in K}\{\#\gamma_{x,y}\ni e\}$$
My approach for a bound follows my intuition for the 2 and 3 dimensional case.
Since the torus is symmetrical, we can consider any arbitrary edge. Consider a coordinate system, where the edge $e$ is in the middle of the grid, such that e is an edge in the $j$-th dimension from vertices $u=(u_1,...,u_{\lfloor \frac L2\rfloor},...,u_d)$ to $v=(u_1,...,u_{\lfloor \frac L2\rfloor+1},...,u_d)$.
Torus with d=2 and L=5
Any edge $e$ is only part of a shortest path, if the starting vertex is, "left" and "below" in the grid system (green) and the ending vertex is "right" and "above" (red).
Using indices, we can write that $x_i\leq u_i = v_i\leq y_i$ for $i\neq j$ and $x_i\leq u_i < v_i\leq y_i$ for $i= j$ must hold.
Now fix an arbitrary vertex in the green part of the coordinate system. For the dimension $j$ there are $\lfloor\frac {L}2\rfloor\leq \frac L2\leq (\frac{L+1}{2})$ relevant vertices in the red sector.
For all other dimensions, there are $(\lceil\frac {L}2\rceil)^{d-1}\leq (\frac{L+1}{2})^{d-1}$ vertices "above" the edge e.
Multiplying these expressions, we find that there are at most $(\frac {L+1}{2})^d$ vertices "right" and "above".
Now, there are $(n(n-1))/2$ possible connection of "n" vertices, therefore, we arrive at $$\frac{(\frac{L+1}{2})^{d}(\frac{L+1}{2}-1)^{d}}{2}$$ connections.
Then the edge "e" is not only used by paths from green to red but also from blue to pink, therefore, we must multiply by 2. Then we arrive at a bound of number of shortest paths of $(\frac{L+1}{2})^d(\frac{L+1}{2}-1)^d$.
Where are the mistakes in my thought process? I have used my calculations for the bottleneck measure to find bounds for the spectral gap of the related transition matrix $P$ (Diaconis & Stroock (1991)). However, calculating the eigenvalues directly for low dimensions and grid sizes have revealed that my considerations are not correct.
Any ideas and remarks are highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Notice that there can be multiple shortest paths between a given pair of vertices. The definitions you've given seem to ignore this.
